# Cannot close mongoose connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

Fruit.find((err, fruits) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    fruits.forEach((fruit) => console.log(fruit.name));
  };

  mongoose.connection.close(function() { process.exit(0); });
});
```

In the above code `mongoose.connection.close(function() { process.exit(0); });`, works but `mongoose.connection.close()`,or `mongoose.disconnect();` dosen'nt work. What do I need to do to make it work? Or suggest some other cleaner way to close connection.

My dependencies are: `"dependencies": { "mongodb": "4.10", "mongoose": "^6.6.6" }`

Comment: How do you identify that `mongoose.connection.close()` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question when I just started with mongoDB, and I realized that most of the time I don't really need the connection to be closed. That it should connect at the start of the application and keep it open.

From what I observed, `.disconnect()` function itself takes some time to get executed. So you can leave it be, setting the a time out doesn't help if you want the connection to disconnect immediately, because even after the function is triggered after the set time, **`disconnect()` itself takes some time to disconnect.**

For some reasons `mongoose.connection.close(function() { process.exit(0); });`, did instantly close the connection for me though.

Answer (score 0):

as said [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/330) this is a timing issue.
you can fix it as follows:

```js
setTimeout( () => {
  mongoose.disconnect()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked great, the connection was closed after the specified time. Ty for for the link as well, helped me understand the issue.